# How can I get an exception thrown when a user mis-types the name of a querystring PM of data type string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, query-string, handleerror

I'm using MVC 3 and vs2010 and VB.NET.
I'm using 'HandleError' on my controller which works nice and easy and automatically detects an unhandled exception and redirects the user to an error page of my choice. However, there's a problem.

Here's an example of an action method I'm using:

```
    <HandleError>
    Public Function ReportAProblem(DespatchNoteNo As String, DespatchNoteItemId As Long) As ActionResult
        Dim uiview As New PickingReportAProblemVM(DespatchNoteNo, DespatchNoteItemId)

        ' Get the data for ReportAProblem
        GetDataForReportAProblem(uiview)

        Return View(uiview)
    End Function
```

When the user manipulates the URL in the following ways, an exception is thrown automatically and the user is redirected to my error page:

- .../?DespatchNoteNo=DN1234&DespatchNoteItemId=A (incorrect data type for DespatchNoteItemId)
- .../?DespatchNoteNo=DN1234&DespatchNoteItem=1 (incorrect parametername for DespatchNoteItemId)

An exception seems to be thrown automatically (please correct me if I'm wrong) which is picked up by HandleError and the user is redirected to my error page.

However, if the user types the following:

- .../?DespatchNote=DN1234&DespatchNoteItemId=1 (incorrect parameter name for DespatchNote)

It seems that there's no exception thrown (please correct me if I'm wrong) and the user is not redirected to my error page, but instead the code just continues.

As far as I can see when I'm debugging, when the action method is called, in all scenarios described above the value of the parameter is set to Nothing.
Again, the difference seems to be that for any parameters of a type OTHER than String an exception is thrown APART FROM parameters of type String where this doesn't seem to be the case.

I'm obviously checking the contents of the variable again later on in the service layer of my application but in the above scenario (i.e. the user has been manipulating the querystring and should have his/her fingers chopped off) I don't want the code to get into the service layer at all but instead have the user redirected to my error page (just like what's happening for non-string data types).

Does anyone know of a way to get an exception thrown if the user manipulates the name of a String type querystring parameter? Or am I going around this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because the `DispatchNoteNo` variable is a string.  Since it is not provided in the URL, it is now an empty string.  No exception will be thrown here.  So you have a few options.

1. Check for `String.IsNullOrEmpty(DispatchNoteNo)` in your controller, redirect if true.
2. Use routing to your advantage -> create a route with these values.  If one is missing, the route will fail.  An example is at the end because I fail at syntax markup this morning...

Here, if one or both of the parameters is not defined or if someone removes one of the route constraints, this route will not match the request.  As long as you do not have a route it will match further down, the server will return a 'No route matched the supplied blah blah blah' (sorry, don't remember the exact wording of this) error

```
routes.MapRoute("Dispatches",
                    "Controller/ReportAProblem/{DispatchNoteNo}/{DespatchNoteItemId}",
                    new { controller = "Controller", action = "ReportAProblem" }
                );
```

Comment: Yes "DispatchNoteNo" is a string, see the declaration of the function "ReportAProblem". Thanks for the 2 options. I thought about using option 1, but I didn't like having to put 3 lines of code (if blablabla then redirect .... end if) for each parameter of type String in each action method. About option 2, am not really sure how that would work for me as I'm not using URLs like .../<val1>/<val2> but I'm using URLs like ...?<pm1>=<val1>&<pm2>=<val2>  instead. Also I'm going to end up with hundreds of action methods so I don't really fancy having to define a route per action method.

Comment: I've just come up with a slight workaround, which I'll add as a possible answer. I'll be interested to hear what you think of that one.

Comment: Do all of your dispatch notes start with DN?  Could you only send the number portion (as an int in your method signature) and append the DN later down the line?  A little more messy, but might solve a good portion of your issues without making lots of routes...

Comment: Tommy, nice idea but unfortunately the prefix will be different quite often. Also, I'm looking for a solution to cope with any querystring parameter of type "String".

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workaround I've come up with.
It's not perfect as I still need 1 line of code for each String type parameter I want to check in an action method, but if that's the closest to perfect I'll accept it.

I've created the following actionfilter:

```
Public Class CheckStringParam
    Inherits ActionFilterAttribute

    Public Property Parameter As String
    Public Property InputValue As String

    Public Overloads Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(filterContext As ActionExecutingContext)
        If Parameter <> String.Empty AndAlso filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(Parameter) Then
            If filterContext.ActionParameters.TryGetValue(Parameter, InputValue) Then
                If InputValue Is Nothing Then
                    Throw (New ArgumentException)
                End If
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

It's basically called with a parameter name. If you've supplied a parameter name and it exists within the context of the action, it will try to get its value. If that succeeds it checks if it is set to Nothing. If so, it throws an exception. This will then automatically be picked up by "HandleError" and the user gets redirected to the user screen.

The action method now looks like this:

```
<CheckStringParam(Parameter:="DespatchNoteNo")>
<HandleError>
Public Function ReportAProblem(DespatchNoteNo As String, DespatchNoteItemId As Long) As ActionResult
    Dim uiview As New PickingReportAProblemVM(DespatchNoteNo, DespatchNoteItemId)

    ' Get the data for ReportAProblem
    GetDataForReportAProblem(uiview)

    Return View(uiview)
End Function
```

There's no other code needed and it will result in the user getting redirected if he/she does manipulate the URL and types in an incorrect parameter name.

I'm interested to hear what people think.